# Extract strings from a pattern in java using Matcher and pattern

Tags: java, regex

If I have a String like this "Error. LineNumber = 2, originalLine = 'ABC', lineErrors = [Special chars found]", I would like to extract

- the line number as '2',
- originalLine as 'ABC' and
- error as 'Special chars found'

I am very new to regex, any pointers would be very helpful. I browsed through few past questions but did not get what I wanted.

Comment: what you tried till now ?

Comment: Tried using pattern = "Parsing error. LineNumber = (\\d+), originalLine = '[\\w]', lineErrors = \\[[\\w]\\]", but I am not getting the result I want. Not sure if it's right!

Comment: pattern = "Parsing error. ....  should probably be "Error....  as "Parsing error" is not in your sample string "Error. Line...."

Answer (score 2):

You can use capturing groups to capture the values. This is the sample code in Java. This works for the specified string but you can tweak and change it accordingly.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "Error. LineNumber = 2, originalLine = 'ABC', lineErrors = [Special chars found]";
    String patternStr = "Error. LineNumber = ([\\S ]+), originalLine = ([\\S ]+), lineErrors = ([\\S ]+)";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.find()) {
        int count = m.groupCount();
        System.out.println("group count is " + count);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            System.out.println(m.group(i+1));
        }
    }
  }
}
```